# VHDL getting a std_logic_vector out of an array of std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I have a Problem. I have an `array` of `std_logic_vector` and I input a `value unsinged(3 downto 0)` and I want to use value as the Index of the `array`.

So far so good but I should get a `std_logic_vector` out of the `array` and put in the Output `segments` (which is also a `std_logic_vector` with the same size) but I get the error:

```
> can't match type conversion with type array type "std_logic_vector"
```

here is my Code:

```
> library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity getarrayvalue is
port(
        value : in unsigned(3 downto 0);
        clk : in std_logic;
        segments : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture v1 of getarrayvalue is
    type rom_type is array(0 to 9) of std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal rom: rom_type :=("1111110","0110000","1101101","1111001","0110011","1011011","1011111","1110000","1111111","1111011");
    signal val_i: integer;

    val_i <= to_integer(value); 

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            segments <= rom_type(val_i);
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ? Thanks!

Comment: Your example doesn't reproduce the error There's a missing `begin` for the architecture. Show your complete and accurate error messages. `segments <= rom_type(val_i);` should be `segments <= rom(val_i);` Note without a constrained subtype the default initial value of `val_i ` is outside the index range of `rom` and that would produce a simulation error when `rom(val_i)` is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to fix it now